# flutter: listview blank divider

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

### Goal

I'd love to have a `ListView` where there are 4 `ListTile`s and a divider right before its last `ListTile`, but I don't want the horizontal line with the `Divider`, only a blank space with customizable height.

### Problem

So far I haven't found a straightforward way other than inserting an empty container before the last two tiles.

The thing is: I have a model `List` behind the `ListView`. I'd love to match the selected items in the list to the ListView. So there had better be a 1-to-1 mapping between data and view. This makes it convenient to configure the looks for selecting the ListTiles. Having a non-data divider in the view skews the mapping, i.e., now I'd have 4 data items, but 5 items in the view. So I couldn't just use

```dart
child: ListTile(
  selected: model[i].isSelected,
)
```

### Question

Am I asking for too much from the `ListView` or is there a straightforward way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did you check `ListView.separated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ListView.separated

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: 25,
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => SizedBox ( height : <height>),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('item $index'),
    );
  },
)
```